# Exploratory Testing within VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I am confused about the Exploratory Testing features. In MTM I can do Exploratory Testing, Explore a work item (this ensures trace-ability) and view my Charters (the notes).

Now:
If I use the Feedback Client 2017 (Windows application), how can I Explore a work item to ensure the Traceability?

If I use the Chrome plugin, How can I view the charter (notes) itself? (not the statistics)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

With Feedback client, there isn’t the way to explore a work item, you need to link work items to the feedback work item.

For Feedback chrome extension, you can check notes in bug’s (Created during session) Repro Steps field.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the strategy Microsoft is choosing here? I find this strange. So we now have three Exploratory Testing capabilities but they have all three a different way of working.